# Issue with first result of my page on Google

Tags: magento, seo, google-search

I’ve 3 Magento stores, but I’m facing a problem with one of them. When I search on Google “Name of my store” the first result of my Magento store is from a CMS page and no my home page, as it supposes to be. Actually, my home page is not a result even from page 2, 3, 4 and 5 (of Google results)

I’ve checked everything as recommended in multiples websites of best practices to Magento SEO, update my robots.txt, update sitemap (I also tried to change priority in sitemap of homepage) and upload it to Google Webmasters, but no way… The first result is a CMS page… Could anyone give me glue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've already posted there and they closed the question because it was not related to magento itself...

Comment: Well it's not about programming so it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your domain is still new and you need to add more external backlinks to your homepage.

Only quality links will help you in your case.

Also try to make HTML sitemap, it will help Google to understand your structure.

Comment: Thank you Nadeem! I'll make a HTML sitemap and after I post here the results. You may be right... My domain is still new and there is few external backlinks...